# Is it possible to use past tense IF with hypothetical with present result?

Tags: modal-verbs, tense-agreement

I am talking to my buddy about going somewhere and I am imagining going if his sister went.

- I would go if your sister went.
- I would go if she would go.

> If that were the case, then **you could count me in**.

vs

> If that were the case, then **you can count me in.**

In the negative form

> If not, then you could count me out.
>
> If not, then you can count me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether you think that the sister is likely to go to the event. If you are hoping that she will be there, you can say

> I'll go if your sister is going. If she is, you can count me in.

If you think she probably won't be there (but are imagining how it would be if she was), you might say

> I would go if your sister was going.
>
> *If that were the case, you could count me in* is correct, but sounds rather formal.

Comment: Thanks,  are you also saying that I cannot u the above ones in the question? I would go if she would go etc?

Comment: _I would go if she would go_ doesn't seem quite right to me, though I'd hesitate to say it was definitely wrong.